What features can be used to estimate both azimuth and elevation angle using a deep learning model?
I am trying to estimate both azimuth and elevation angle, for which I simulated a URA, whose code is given below.
SNR_dB_vec = -20:5:10;  % SNR levels 
Max_a = 180; 
Max_e = 90;
grid_res = 5;   
sVar = 1;
p = 100; % Number of time snapshots
fs = 10^7; % Sampling frequency
fc = 10^6; % Center frequency of narrowband sources
Mx = 12; % Number of array elements on x axis
My = 8; % Number of array elements on y axis
cSpeed = 3*10^8 ; % Speed of light
dist = 180; % Sensors (i.e., antennas) spacing in meters in both x and 
%y axes
SOURCE_K = 4; % no.of sources*2 (for source 1 col1 and col3 are for 
%azimuth and for source 2 col2 and col4 are elevation)
% The training sets
azimuth_grid = -Max_a:grid_res:Max_a;
elevation_grid = -Max_e:grid_res:Max_e;
[Az, El] = meshgrid(azimuth_grid, elevation_grid);
% Number of training samples
num_samples = 2500;

% Initialize doa matrix to store the results
doa = zeros(num_samples, 4);

for i = 1:num_samples
    % Randomly pick values for each column
    while true
        az1 = azimuth_grid(randi(numel(azimuth_grid)));
        el1 = elevation_grid(randi(numel(elevation_grid)));
        az2 = azimuth_grid(randi(numel(azimuth_grid)));
        el2 = elevation_grid(randi(numel(elevation_grid)));

        % Check if all values in the row are unique
        if numel(unique([az1, el1, az2, el2])) == 4
            doa(i, :) = [az1, el1, az2, el2];
            break;
        end
    end
end

G = size(doa,1); 
S = length(SNR_dB_vec);             % number of the SNR levels
N = 64;  %total number of antenna elements
R_ECM = zeros(Mx, Mx,2,G,S);     % Expected covariance matrix (ECM)
R_SCM = zeros(Mx, Mx,2,G,S);     % Sampled covariance matrix (SCM)
for i=1:S
    SNR_dB = SNR_dB_vec(i);
    noise_power = 10^(-SNR_dB/10);
    r_the = zeros(Mx, Mx,2,G);    % Temporary expected covariance variable at a SNR level
    r_sam = zeros(Mx, Mx ,2,G); % Temporary Sampled covariance variable at a SNR level
    for ii=1:G
        SOURCE_angles = doa(ii,:);
        Ax = zeros(Mx, SOURCE_K);
        Ay = zeros(My - 1, SOURCE_K);
        for k = 1:2:SOURCE_K
            Ax(:, k) = exp(-1i*2*pi*fc*dist*(1/cSpeed)*(0:Mx-1)' ...
                *cosd(SOURCE_angles(k))*sind(SOURCE_angles(k+1)));
            Ay(:, k) = exp(-1i*2*pi*fc*dist*(1/cSpeed)*(1:My-1)' ...
                *sind(SOURCE_angles(k))*sind(SOURCE_angles(k+1)));
        end
        A = [Ax; Ay]; % Steering matrix of all sensors
        % The Expected covariance matrix for a angle-pair
        Ry_the = A*diag(ones(SOURCE_K,1))*A' + noise_power*eye(Mx+My-1);
        RMx_the = Ry_the(1:Mx, 1:Mx);
        RMy_the = Ry_the(Mx+1:Mx+My-1, Mx+1:Mx+My-1); % Original sensor is omitted
        RMy_the = [Ry_the(Mx+1:Mx+My-1, 1), RMy_the];
        RMy_the = [[Ry_the(1, 1), Ry_the(1, Mx+1:Mx+My-1)]; RMy_the]; % (My x My)

         % The Sampled covariance matrix for a angle-pair
        S = sqrt(sVar)*randn(SOURCE_K, p).*exp(1i*(2*pi*fc*repmat((1:p)/fs, SOURCE_K, 1)));
        X = A*S;
        noiseCoeff = 1;
        Eta = sqrt(noiseCoeff)*randn(Mx + My - 1, p);
        Y = X + Eta;
        Ry_sam = Y*Y'/p; 
        RMx_sam = Ry_sam(1:Mx, 1:Mx); % covariance matrix of signals received by ULA on X-axis
        RMy_sam = Ry_sam(Mx+1:Mx+My-1, Mx+1:Mx+My-1); % Original sensor is omitted
        RMy_sam = [Ry_sam(Mx+1:Mx+My-1, 1), RMy_sam];
        RMy_sam = [[Ry_sam(1, 1), Ry_sam(1, Mx+1:Mx+My-1)]; RMy_sam]; % (My x My)
    
        % Real and Imaginary part for the ECM
        r_the(:,:,1,ii) = real(RMx_the); %%% when I am only trying to estimate the azimuth angles
        r_the(:,:,2,ii) = imag(RMx_the);
        % Real and Imaginary part for the SCM
        r_sam(:,:,1,ii) = real(RMx_sam); %%% when I am only trying to estimate the azimuth angles
        r_sam(:,:,2,ii) = imag(RMx_sam);
    end
    disp(['Processing SNR level:', num2str(i)]);
    R_ECM(:,:,:,:,i) = r_the;
    R_SCM(:,:,:,:,i) = r_sam;
end
% The angles Ground Truth
angles = doa(:,1:2:4); %%% when I am only trying to estimate the azimuth angles
% Save the DATA
h5create(filename_ECM,'/angles',size(angles));
h5write(filename_ECM, '/angles', angles);
h5create(filename_ECM,'/ECM',size(R_ECM));
h5write(filename_ECM, '/ECM', R_ECM);
h5disp(filename_ECM);
h5create(filename_SCM,'/angles',size(angles));
h5write(filename_SCM, '/angles', angles);
h5create(filename_SCM,'/SCM',size(R_SCM));
h5write(filename_SCM, '/SCM', R_SCM);
h5disp(filename_SCM);

I am using the deep learning model from the paper "Robust DOA Estimation Using Deep ComplexValued Convolutional Networks with Sparse Prior".  In the paper they have used a ULA for predicting only one angle.
Firstly I tried to use the same model, and instead of different source angles at different columns, I used the azimuth angle in col1 and elevation in col2 for a single source system.
Similarly if we have 2 sources then col1 and col2 corresponds to the azimuth and elevation for source 1 and col3 and col4 corresponds to the azimuth and elevation for col2.
But this method is not providing accurate estimation, so I was thinking of using 2 separate models, one for estimating azimuth and another for elevation.
But in that case, I am not sure if I can use the expected and sample covariance matrix as inputs, because the covariance matrix is formed by the combination of both azimuth and elevation.
So, can anyone suggest what input features can I use, if I want to train 2 separate models ?

Are you doing this out of an interest in finding angles in this manner? Or have you not explored other methods. I don't have access to the paper but using a CNN just to estimate the angle of arrival is unnecessary.

Estimating azimuth and elevation is akin to two-dimensional sampling, which would necessitate a block covariance matrix. I would work on getting other DOA estimates, like MUSIC, working for 2-D first, because then you can be sure your covariance matrix is properly formed. Also, agreeing with Envidia, Neural Net methods are only useful in very low SNR very low snapshot cases, and require accurate training. You'll notice the CNN methods eventually perform worse in more practical scenarios than the others.

@Envidia, yes I am doing this out of interest, as there has been quite some literature on how to estimate DOA using neural networks, but there's not enough papers for 2D DOA estimation. So, I was just interested to try that. If I have to use a neural network then what features might be suitable as an input?

@Baddioes I have used a 2D Music algorithm to check if the simulated covariance matrix is correct and using the MUSIC algorithm I am able to estimate the DOAs. But I am not sure where I am going wrong with the neural network

I had this idea of using the ULAs in the x and y-axis of a URA to estimate the azimuth and elevation angles separately, do you think it is a practical solution? Any suggestions will be helpful.

It's honestly hard to say where you might be going wrong with the neural net. There's so many possible points along the path of training, validation, and testing where it could go wrong. I would probably start with your idea of independently estimating the azimuth and elevation angles and see if that works with your model. If it doesn't, then you know something is wrong with your model. If it does work, then something is wrong with your extension of the model to two dimensions.

@Baddioes, to calculate azimuth and elevation angles of a URA separately, I have modified the input to the nn s.t. while estimating the azimuth the input cov matrix is RMx_the = Ry_the(1:Mx, 1:Mx); and Ry_the is calculated using both azimuth and elevation. For this input the labels are only the azimuth angles, in my case angles = doa(:,1:2:4) (as col1 and col2 correspond to azimuth). For elevation, RMy_sam =Ry_sam(Mx+1:Mx+My-1, Mx+1:Mx+My-1); RMy_sam = [Ry_sam(Mx+1:Mx+My-1, 1), RMy_sam]; RMy_sam = [[Ry_sam(1, 1), Ry_sam(1, Mx+1:Mx+My-1)]; RMy_sam]; Is this a correct approch?

@ananya, Where is the net implementation? How can you be sure it is good?

@Royi, I tried the net implementation on a ULA and it worked with a decent accuracy in estimation

@ananya, If you share the whole code, we'll be able to assist.

@Baddioes, as you mentioned the main challenge of doa estimation that can be tried to solve using a nn is the low snr and low snapshot cases, can you suggest some method, on how and which nn can be suitable? I trained the cnn and the performance is not that well for low snr, how can I improve the performance?

I’m not an ML expert, but this is where my understanding begins to break down on how this might be feasible. The way I see it, you would need to set up a discretized grid of possible DOAs, each one being its own class. You would then need to generate a large amount of data for each class. The more classes you have, the more data you need. For example, if you are sampling every 1 degree in the -45 to 45 degree range, you would have 90 classes, and you would likely need thousands of data points at varying SNR and noise distributions for each possible DOA and a very large neural network.

I’m just not seeing how this is realistic in any way, particularly because the data takes longer to propagate through a larger neural net, making it less likely to use in real time.

@Royi, I have shared the code in this post, maybe you can assist based on the code. https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/47222/89091

@Baddioes, The current signal model assumes stationary sources, I wanted to know, how will the signal model change incase of moving targets, will the array manifold change from A_moving(t)=A_stationary⋅exp(−i2πΔf⋅t), where Δf is the Doppler shift frequency. Is there any other parameter that should be considered in order to make the simulation close to real scenarios.

The DOA is related to the phase shift across the elements at a given time $t$. So, the doppler return shouldn't make a difference since it is a phase difference. However, the phase shift assumption is only valid over a narrowband. You likely need a filterbank to filter the signal at each element, and then do DOA across the channels at the output of each filter.

@Baddioes, since I have trained 2 separate nn, one for azimuth and another for elevation. Now, suppose I get raw data in the form of range gate vs pulses and I know the array geometry is URA, with say Mx sensors along x axis and My sensors along y axis. Then from the raw data computing sample covariance matrix, Ry_sam = Y*Y'/p; and then splitting them into RMx_sam = Ry_sam(1:Mx, 1:Mx); and RMy_sam = [[Ry_sam(1, 1), Ry_sam(1, Mx+1:Mx+My-1)]; RMy_sam]; work? Also, does no.of snapshots/observation is same as the no.of pulses?
